# R column filtration

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been working with some data at my work and I am trying to filter columns based on specific rows but I have been unsuccessful so far. Can anyone please help me out? Let me explain what I am trying to achieve. I have a dataset which displays the following information

```
    person_id|custody_start|custody_end|contact_month|month_start     |month_end |contact_date
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |February 20  |03/01/2020      |02/28/2020|26/02/2020    
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |March 20     |03/01/2020      |03/31/2020|12/03/2020    
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |April 20     |04/01/2020      |04/30/2020|11/04/2020  
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |May 20       |05/01/2020      |05/31/2020|12/05/2020 
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |June 20      |06/01/2020      |06/30/2020|11/06/2020  
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |July 20      |07/01/2020      |07/31/2020|12/07/2020
```

The data displays the same record multiple times but it is a record of the contact made each month and the date the contact was made each month. Basically what I am trying to achieve here is to filter out the column where the person was not in custody for the whole calendar month (from the 1st until the 30th or 31st of each month) we are not looking at 30 days from any date, but the calendar month. So in Feb 20 and July 20 the person was not in custody for the whole month as you can see the person entered custody on the 23rd of Feb and left custody on the 17th of July. So the first and the last month in this case won't count. There are multiple records like this for each person_id so I can not just remove the first and the last column of each child. I just need to keep the records where the person stayed in custody for the whole calendar month

My final result should look something like this

```
    person_id|custody_start|custody_end|contact_month|month_start     |month_end |contact_date
       26321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |March 20     |03/01/2020      |03/31/2020|12/03/2020    
       26321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |April 20     |04/01/2020      |04/30/2020|11/04/2020  
       26321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |May 20       |05/01/2020      |05/31/2020|12/05/2020 
       26321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |June 20      |06/01/2020      |06/30/2020|11/06/2020
```

I would appreciate any kind of help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
dat = read.table(text='person_id|custody_start|custody_end|contact_month|month_start     |month_end |contact_date
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |February 20  |02/01/2020      |02/28/2020|26/02/2020    
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |March 20     |03/01/2020      |03/31/2020|12/03/2020    
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |April 20     |04/01/2020      |04/30/2020|11/04/2020  
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |May 20       |05/01/2020      |05/31/2020|12/05/2020 
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |June 20      |06/01/2020      |06/30/2020|11/06/2020  
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |July 20      |07/01/2020      |07/31/2020|12/07/2020',sep="|",header = TRUE)


dat %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains("custody"),contains("month_")),
            function(x) as.character(x) %>% mdy(.)) %>% 
  mutate(contact_date = dmy(as.character(contact_date))) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(month_start >= custody_start & month_end <= custody_end)

  person_id custody_start custody_end contact_month month_start  month_end contact_date
1  13126321    2020-02-23  2020-07-17 March 20       2020-03-01 2020-03-31   2020-03-12
2  13126321    2020-02-23  2020-07-17 April 20       2020-04-01 2020-04-30   2020-04-11
3  13126321    2020-02-23  2020-07-17 May 20         2020-05-01 2020-05-31   2020-05-12
4  13126321    2020-02-23  2020-07-17 June 20        2020-06-01 2020-06-30   2020-06-11
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried this and though the code does work, for some reason it is making all the contact_date data to be "NA"

Comment: Could you try now?