# filter on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been working with some data at my work and I am trying to filter columns based on specific rows but I have been unsuccessful so far. Can anyone please help me out? Let me explain what I am trying to achieve. I have a dataset which displays the following information

```
    person_id|custody_start|custody_end|contact_month|month_start     |month_end |contact_date
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |February 20  |02/01/2020      |02/28/2020|02/26/2020    
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |March 20     |03/01/2020      |03/31/2020|03/12/2020    
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |April 20     |04/01/2020      |04/30/2020|04/11/2020  
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |May 20       |05/01/2020      |05/31/2020|05/12/2020 
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |June 20      |06/01/2020      |06/30/2020|06/11/2020  
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |July 20      |07/01/2020      |07/31/2020|07/12/2020
```

What I want is to filter out the columns where the contact_date is in the same month as custody_start or custody_end. So in this case the 1st column and the last column should be filtered out and we should only have data from March til June.

The final output should be like this

```
    person_id|custody_start|custody_end|contact_month|month_start     |month_end |contact_date
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |March 20     |03/01/2020      |03/31/2020|03/12/2020    
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |April 20     |04/01/2020      |04/30/2020|04/11/2020  
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |May 20       |05/01/2020      |05/31/2020|05/12/2020 
    13126321 |02/23/2020   |07/17/2020 |June 20      |06/01/2020      |06/30/2020|06/11/2020
```

Comment: Can you share a small example of your data? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R column filtration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66532494/r-column-filtration)

Comment: @jvargh7 no that post did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  filter(month(contact_date) != month(custody_start))
```

Note: this requires your two columns being in a proper (or coercible) date format.

---

**UPDATE** (based on TO's question in the comments):

> is there a way to check if a record in the dataframe was in custody
> for the full calendar month?

```
df <- data.frame(start = as.Date(c("2/23/2020", "2/1/2020", "2/1/2021", "7/1/1900"), "%m/%d/%Y"),
                 end   = as.Date(c("2/25/2020", "2/28/2020", "2/28/2021", "7/31/1900"),"%m/%d/%Y"))

#        start        end
# 1 2020-02-23 2020-02-25
# 2 2020-02-01 2020-02-28
# 3 2021-02-01 2021-02-28
# 4 1900-07-01 1900-07-31

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(start_help = start - days(1),
         end_help   = end   + days(1),
         full_month = if_else(month(start) == month(end) &
                              (month(start) == month(start_help) + 1 | month(start) == month(start_help) - 11) &
                              (month(end)   == month(end_help)   - 1 | month(end)   == month(end_help)   + 11),
                              "yes",
                              "no")) %>%
  select(-start_help, -end_help)

#        start        end full_month
# 1 2020-02-23 2020-02-25         no
# 2 2020-02-01 2020-02-28         no
# 3 2021-02-01 2021-02-28        yes
# 4 1900-07-01 1900-07-31        yes
```

Note: this is a relatively naive approach, i.e. it doesn't check if the year of the start and end date are also the same. However, from your data above, it seems you are staying within one year, so might be fine after all.

Comment: thank you so much. This worked and I now have the right columns I need. One more question, is there a way to check if a record in the dataframe was in custody for the full calendar month? I don't want to check 30 dates from any given date but I want to know if a record is there for the full calendar month.

Comment: If the solution worked, please accept the answer (or if others answer and you like their answer better, then accept their answer) so that others could potentially benefit from the solution.

Comment: as to your other question. I don't have a solution at hand. What could be a work around is: add one day to the custody end date. Subtract one day from the custody start date (familiarize yourself with the lubridate package and you'll see how that works). Then check for the following condition: custody start and custody end date have the same month AND the new custordy start date that we just created is one month lower then the original one AND the new custody end date is one month higher than the original one.

Comment: So if your start date is Feb 1, then the new one becomes Jan 31. If your end date is Feb 28 (or 29 depending on the year), it becomes Mar 1. Original custody start and end have the same month. The new custody dates are one month lower (Jan instead of Feb) and one month higher (March than Feb).

Comment: I guess there's a smarter solution, but it should work.